# Is the term "method" defined by the C++ Standard?

Tags: c++, terminology, language-lawyer

The term "method" is often used to discuss C++ code. Does the standalone term have a well-defined meaning in C++ or is it ambiguous? Is it acceptable to use the term by itself, or should it be qualified (e.g. a "class method" or "virtual method"), or should it be simply avoided altogether?

Comment: The spec uses the terms like `function` , `member function` , `virtual function`, not method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would avoid this term entirely, as it is clear what you mean by "member function", but not "method" - that you asked this question is proof enough.

However, normative appearances of the word "method" in the C++14 standard are

- In the content list:

  > 17.5 **Method of description** (Informative)

  This is repeated in the title of that section.
- [basic.compound]:

  > **These methods** of constructing types can be applied recursively;
- [cpp.include]

  > **The method** by which a sequence
  >   of preprocessing tokens between a `<` and a `>` preprocessing token pair or a pair of `"` characters is combined
  >   into a single header name preprocessing token is implementation-defined.
- [library.general]

  > The following subclauses describe the definitions (17.3), **method of description (17.5)**, [..]
- In table 32, `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is mentioned.
- In stage 2 of `num_get`'s `do_get`:

  > For arithmetic types, `punct.thousands_sep()` characters are inserted
  >   into the sequence as determined by the value returned by
  >   `punct.do_grouping()` using **the method** described in 22.4.3.1.2
- [forwardlist.modifiers]:

  > Otherwise, inserts `sz - distance(begin(), end())` elements at the end of
  >   the list such that each new element, `e`, is initialized by **a method** equivalent to calling `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct(get_allocator(), std::addressof(e), c)`.
- [filebuf.virtuals]:

  > Behaves according to the description of
  >   `basic_streambuf<charT,traits>::uflow()`, with the specialization that a
  >   sequence of characters is read from the input with **the same method** as
  >   used by `underflow`.

The term is clearly never referring to a "member function".

Comment: This essentially copies part of my answer: *`a simple Google search reveals more occurrences of this term.`*.

Answer (score 15):

The term ***method*** is not defined in the C++ standard.  The terminology uses ***member function*** instead.

Bjarne Stroustrup however defines the term *method* in his own [glossary](http://www.stroustrup.com/glossary.html) as *virtual member function*. So this shows evidence that the term is acceptable.

Comment: Good answer. But *virtual* member function is not the same as member function, and, more importantly, it's not the default for a member function (which is, by default, non-virtual).

Comment: Which makes it more ambiguous. Although, frankly, when I see "method" used in non-standard terminology, I always think about "member function".

Comment: @GiulioFranco I agree.  The usual deifinition for OOp is to call data attributes and behaviour methods.  I'm not sure why Bjarne Stroustrup sees it as virtual. It's possible that he makes reference to a method definition which implies polymorphism (i.e. a behaviour associated to the object not its class).

Comment: There are a lot of things Bjarne does and whether or not each one is "acceptable" is up for debate.

Comment: I think it's simply that the languages which first defined the term "method" defined it as polymorphic. As far as I know, no language uses the term method to denote non-virtual member functions, so it's better to attach polymorphism to the term, for conformance.

Comment: @GiulioFranco - in Java, a final method is still a method.

Comment: @PeteBecker But a final method is still virtual, isn't it? Take C++'s `final` for example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final . It's only usable on a `virtual` function.

Comment: @chbaker0 Java `final` method should be the same as C++ `final override`. Still formally virtual, but the compiler is allowed to inline it if it can

Answer (score 1):

The [C++ standard](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) makes no mention of the term `method`. It should be noted that the [official C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance) *does* make use of this term, but to describe a `virtual` function; a [simple Google search](https://www.google.gg/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:https:%2F%2Fisocpp.org%20%27method%27) reveals more occurrences of this term.

I've never seen the term `method` in an IDE (Visual Studio), but I've seen the term `member function`. In my opinion `method` is a 'one size fits all' term.

Answer (score 1):

The term method had been historically used as a synonym of the procedure of an object. Considering, an object has both data and behaviour, it is this behaviour which was referred as method. 
Tracing backward, I could find a reference to the usage of the term method when referring to an MIT ALGOL version, AED-0

[Quoting wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#History)

> MIT ALGOL version, AED-0, linked data structures ("plexes", in that
>   dialect) directly with procedures, prefiguring what were later termed
>   "messages", "methods", and "member functions".

Over the years method had been an integral part of Object Oriented Analysis and Design and Object-oriented programming. Now C++ evolved as a procedural language where it extended C a procedural language to have object oriented capabilities. C had the concept of structure, and the data elements were called members. Refer [Methods in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Methods_in_C.2B.2B).
To not break the lineage, C++ continued to call the elements of structured and the newer genre class as members.

Now, to differentiate between data and functions, instead of introducing a new terminology, it extended this terminology to call data members and member functions. Member functions which supported dynamic binding were called virtual functions.

So, strictly speaking, official references refrains from using the terminology methods when referring to member functions. The terminology is most prevalent among the people who have a more Object Oriented background. So if you want to remain unambiguous, it is best to use the terminology as

- data member
- member function
- virtual functions

Comment: Please use quotation formatting to make it clear how much of this is in your own words, and how much of it was written by someone else.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: Please elaborate which part is not clear ? I had appropriately quoted as required. Downvoter: Can you please help me to understand which part is not helpful or incorrect?

Comment: What makes you assume the downvotes are "whimsical" or "without any appropriate reason"?

Comment: My first comment sufficiently explained the problem. I believe you have now adequately rectified it.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: What You mentioned in your first comment does not in any way makes the answer unhelpful. Moreover (not a justification), the answer was being formatted while you commented. In any case, as far as I can see, 2 downvotes, when the contents were correct and helpful, does not warrants for a downvote.

Comment: "Method" was introduced by Smalltalk. In older programming languages the word "method" is not used. So I think that the word "method" is not "historical" enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here my analysis regarding the word ***method***.

I did a scan on official documentation (standards, specifications, etc.) on several programming languages.

http://componentsprogramming.com/using-the-right-terms-method/

Adequate taxonomy (not dependent on any programming languages) will be published in a future article.

Regarding to C++, the correct terminology is: *member/non-member function*.
Some people use member/free functions.